# Javascript Alert prompt prior to reload()

Tags: javascript

I have an existing icon that performs a javascript reload of the page.  How do I add an alert with an ok or cancel prior to executing the reload?

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.location.reload()"><img src="img/reload.png" alt="Reset" name="Reset" width="32" height="32" align="middle" id="Reset" /></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command you're looking for is [`confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.confirm):

```
if (confirm('Are you sure')) window.location.reload()
```

Answer (score 1):

Well if you do a little bit of googling, it is quite simple to find.
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp

```
confirm("sometext");


if (confirm("Press a button"))
{
  x="You pressed OK!";
  window.location.reload();
}
else
{
  x="You pressed Cancel!";
}
```

This should help.